# How to change values of another textbox based on change event of combo box

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am crating one small module in Spring+Hibernate framework.

In my jsp page, on click event of one dropdown box(values are getting from database) i am setting values of next two input box.eg If suppose i selected country(values are coming from one table say TBL_ABC ) then accordingly my city(values are again coming from same same table TBL_ABC) values should change.

kindly suggest me some good and standard ways to accomplish this .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accomplish this with help of ajax requests. When your jsp gets loaded for the first time, you need to pass the list of countries(name,id) to the jsp and create the dropdown box with these values(you are already doing this). The lable will be the name and value will be the country id(of course).

Then on click of the dropdown box you can get the selected item value in your javascript function and then call the ajax request mapped to one of the controller methods that will return you the list of cities based on the country id passed. And then fill the list of cities with these values.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Yes you can do. But that is not recommended if you have large number of (country,city) mapping values in your database. The standard way to do this is using ajax. And I think that is what you are looking forward to. :-)